# How can we make docker-compose exit with an error if any of its services exits with an error?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration

#### The Problem

How can I cause `docker-compose up` to exit with an error if *any* of its services/containers exits with an error? There is the `--abort-on-container-exit` flag, but that always exits with a `0` exit code. There is also the `--exit-code-from <my_service>` argument, but that will only exit with the exit code that `<my_service>` exited with.

An alternative form of the same question: how can I know if *any* of the docker containers run by the previous `docker-compose up` command exited with an error?

#### A Janky Solution

I came up with [one solution](https://gist.github.com/epeters3/cb1147145e5b4b09e4b92ef0a56e4186) where you monitor the `stdout` given by `docker-compose`, and grep for instances of the string `<service> exited with error code <code>`, but I think that approach is prone to false positives, and also introduces an external dependency. I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Raphael! I am trying to script something. Specifically, i'm using docker-compose to execute tests in a CI environment. I want to fail the CI testing job if any container exits with an error. I like how you mentioned `docker ps --filter`. I could potentially use that and parse out the exit codes, but I think `docker ps --filter` lists all dead/exited docker containers, and not just the ones from the most recent execution of `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to script something or just run everything and have some feedback ?

for exemple, you can start all your containers with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

then you do this command to see dead containers.

```
docker ps --filter status=dead
docker ps --filter status=exited
```

Theses are possible statuses :
created, restarting, running, removing, paused, exited and dead

If this is for production purpose you should consider using docker swarm. It works well even for a single node. it will take care of orchestration which is way more than compose does. It can automatically restart the service on healthcheck failure,  do rollbacks, achieve zero downtime deployment, etc.